# How to check if partition is Bitlocker encrypted

Tags: windows-7, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I am creating a Virtual Harddisk but I want to confirm that the partition on which I am creating VHD is not bitlocker encrypted. I am using windows 7 home premium.

Thanks a ton..

Comment: If the partition was encrypted, how could you access it?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium doesn't have Bitlocker.

Comment: Just don't encrypt the partition.  Besides the copy of Windows you are using does not even give you the ability to encrypt the partition.

Comment: Since there's no bitlocker tag, this Q is related: http://superuser.com/questions/820865/bitlocker-vs-encrypting-file-system-efs-on-windows-7

Comment: @CeesTimmerman - Read the title of the question.  This question was specifically about Bitlocker and only Bitlocker.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for clearing that up, as the non-Enterprise Windows also specified in the question only has EFS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click *Start*, click *Control Panel*, click *Security*, and then click *BitLocker Drive Encryption*.

You can also [access it from the command-line](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/how-to-manage-bitlocker-from-command-line.html) (elevated):

```
manage-bde -status
```

Comment: The first method doesn't work on editions that don't have Bitlocker (at least not on Win7 Professional), but the second one does, so +1.

Comment: @Ramhound I think that point is deserving of being posted as an answer - if Home Premium can even access a partition, then it's not Bitlocker-encrypted. Definitely does answer the OP's question, and is even easier than using a command-line utility.

Comment: @Ramhound `manage-bde -unlock {-RecoveryPassword Password | -RecoveryKey PathToExternalKeyFile} Volume [-ComputerName Name]`

Comment: @Ramhound It is a reply to your seemingly false comment that "Windows 7 Home Premium cannot even access a storage device protected by Bitlocker." based on the accepted answer's command and "Applies To: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2" statement [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875513(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_unlock).